# Visual C++ 2008 doesn't recognize Windows declared types

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I have a program that doesn't seem to recognize declared types in the latest U3D software.  There's a line

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI* GMI)(HMON, LPMONITORINFOEX);
```

which gets the error:

Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPMONITORINFOEX'    c:\Projects\U3D\Source\RTL\Platform\Common\Win32\IFXOSRender.cpp    28

and a line

```
MONITORINFOEX miMon;
```

which gets

Error   5   error C2065: 'miMon' : undeclared identifier    c:\Projects\U3D\Source\RTL\Platform\Common\Win32\IFXOSRender.cpp    49
Error   3   error C2065: 'MONITORINFOEX' : undeclared identifier    c:\Projects\U3D\Source\RTL\Platform\Common\Win32\IFXOSRender.cpp    49

The program's first non-comment statement is `#include <windows.h>`, which includes `winuser.h`, which defines these identifiers.  In Visual Studio, I can right-click on them and go to the definition (a typedef) and from the typedef to the struct.  `WINAPI` is defined in `WinDef.h`, so that seems to be working.  There are no redefinitions of `LPMONITORINFOEX` or `MONITORINFOEX` in any other file.

So, how can this be happening, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is something is up with your WINVER define.  If you look at winuser.h, those are only defined in the block:

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
```

Is it possible that your WINVER is incorrectly set?

Comment: Thank you very much - it was 0400.  I've changed it, and the errors have gone away.